# Stack Exchange v. 1.0.71 Android Crashes

Tags: bug, android-app

Occasionally when a question is loading, the Stack Exchange app crashes. More information:

- Phone model: LG E970 (LG Optimus G AT&T Model, not rooted)
- Android Version: 4.1.2
- Reproduced about 50% of the time when opening a question

I have seen other crash reports about previous versions of the app, but I have yet to see any about version 1.0.71 for Android. If any other information is needed, please let me know.